# File attachments showing as message entities in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Recently we've noticed that the Microsoft Graph API has been returning file attachments as message entities returned from the /me/messages endpoint.

The scenario to reproduce is as follows:

- Send yourself an email (or have someone else send you an email) with one or more file attachments
- Run the following query in Graph Explorer: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
- Notice that there will be one object which represents the email itself (this is correct behaviour) and one or more objects which are representations of the file attachments.

It's also worth noting that these attachment "messages" have the same subject as the original email, the body content is set to the file content of the attachment (if the attachment is a document), there are no senders or recipients, they have an isRead status of true, and an isDraft status of true. Utter nonsense!

[image: Attachment as message]

I can only assume this is a bug in the Graph API - I can't see any reason why this would happen by design. It's also worth noting that I've been working with the Graph API for around 9 months and this behaviour has only recently started happening.

Could someone from Microsoft please get in touch regarding this as soon as possible? This is a major bug in the API which will undoubtedly break most applications using it. It's also a great concern that a supposedly stable v1.0 is being changed underneath us. Why not use v1.1 or v2.0 for the next release?

Comment: Thank you David for letting us know about this issue. I'm seeing the same thing as you except my attachment content is not in the body of the message; it is also interesting to note that the 'attachment message' is marked as a draft. I've informed the product owners about this.

Comment: Thanks for the update Michael, fingers crossed this will be fixed soon then.

Comment: Hi @MichaelMainer-MSFT we have noticed this problem has started occurring again today, would you be able to advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for reporting! I see this behavior as well if I retrieve messages via the `/me/messages` endpoint. If I retrieve via `/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages`, I do not. This is actually an important clue.

I looked at the `parentFolderId` of the messages. For the one that is "right", it was the ID of the Inbox. For the other, it was not. Whatever ID it is, I can't retrieve it via the API (I get a 404). So it's likely this is a hidden folder.

Playing with the IDs, I was able to convert to a MAPI ID and open it with [MFCMapi](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/). It turns out it's the **Files** folder. So I think the bug here is that `/me/messages` should not include the **Files** folder when returning results. I'll log a bug with our development team.

Comment: Thanks for investigating Jason, I don't suppose you'd be able to give a rough estimate on when we could expect a fix...?

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this, but I wanted to follow up. I can no longer reproduce this problem. Is this still happening for you?