# Attached Word docs wrongly showing as message entities in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

The Microsoft Graph API is wrongly returning Word doc file attachments as message entities returned from the /me/messages endpoint.

The scenario to reproduce is as follows:

1. Send yourself an email (or have someone else send you an email) with one or more Word doc file attachments
2. Run the following query in Graph Explorer: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
3. Notice that there will be one object which represents the email itself (this is correct behaviour) and one or more objects which are representations of the file attachments.

Could someone from Microsoft please get in touch regarding this as soon as possible? This is a major bug in the API which will probably cause issues for most applications using it.

*P.S. This issue was previously raised and fixed, but it has reared it's head again...*
[File attachments showing as message entities in Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872688/file-attachments-showing-as-message-entities-in-microsoft-graph-api)

*May I also suggest that some automated tests are written around this issue to prevent it from happening again in the future?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue, it should be resolved in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arun - any ideas when this will be fixed?

Comment: In the next few weeks, sorry I can't give you an exact date. If you don't see it by next month please ping me directly - https://twitter.com/arunvaradhar